# Find sequence for given generating function $\frac{ \frac{3x}{2} + \frac{3}{2}}{ 3 - x }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I have generating function

$$A(x) = \frac{ \frac{3x}{2} + \frac{3}{2}}{ 3 - x }$$

and I need to find a sequence from it.

This was my approach:

$$ \frac{ \frac{3x}{2} + \frac{3}{2}}{ 3 - x } = \frac{-3}{2} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{3}} $$

$ \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{3}} $ is generating function for $a_n = \frac{1}{3^n}$ so I though that the whole sequence $(c_n)_0^\infty$ would be:

$$c_n =  \frac{-3}{2} + \frac{2}{3^n} $$

but according to wolfram it is wrong, where I am doing a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac32\cdot\frac{x+1}{3-x}&=\frac12\cdot\frac{x+1}{1-\frac{x}3}\\
&=\frac12\left(x\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac13\right)^nx^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac13\right)^nx^n\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac13\right)^nx^{n+1}+\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac13\right)^nx^n\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac13\right)^{n-1}x^n+\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac13\right)^nx^n+1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\left(\frac13\right)^{n-1}+\left(\frac13\right)^n\right)x^n+1\right)\\
&=\frac12+\frac12\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac43\right)\left(\frac13\right)^{n-1}x^n\\
&=\frac12+2\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac13\right)^nx^n\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $a_0=\dfrac12$, and $a_n=\dfrac2{3^n}$ for $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\frac{3}{6}\frac{x}{1 - \frac{x}{3}} + \frac{3}{6} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{3}}$$

and use that $$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{3}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigg( \frac{x}{3}\bigg)^n$$

Comment: I did that but what would be series for $\frac{x}{1-\frac{x}{3}}$?

Comment: multiply the given series by $x$.

Comment: Yes, of course. I am suppose to write a formula of the series as a formula for $a_n$ element though. Without sums and infinity etc.

Comment: (Out of curiosity, why is my approach not working?)

Comment: What do you mean $a_n$ element? Do you want the coefficients of each term of the series? Jot down a few terms and you see a pattern

Comment: Yes, I wrote a series I meant a sequence though. Sorry for that, it has been a really long day.

Comment: Well I could do it that way, by a pattern but I can use a generating function to do that. That is point of this exercise I was given.

Comment: It should be the same procedure I guess, by the definition I got of generating functions.